# How to switch the order of files (original and modified) in Eclipse Compare window?

Tags: eclipse, diff

When comparing two files, for example during a commit, Eclipse shows the original version on the right and modified on the left:

[image: Compare Window Screenshot]

However, I would prefer to see the original version on the left and modified on the right. Is it possible?

Comment: You can [vote up the bug here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=213780).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse Neon.2 (4.6.2) has a button to swap the views:

[image]

Comment: It took the time to be implemented, but it is here (not sure from when).

Answer (score 1):

1. You can either swap the views for every compare, as [one answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42066221/4955498):

   [image: button to swap compare order]
2. Or you can make the swapped order be the default for all compares:

   Windows --> Preferences --> General --> Compare/Patch

   Select the **Text Compare** tab, and mark the check-box of **Swap left and right**

   [image: Compare/Patch -> Text Compare -> Swap left and right]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just depending of which file you're selecting first. I mean, choose a file, and select compare to .. and choose another one. Next choose the second one and compare to the first one, they'll swap in your window :)

Comment: This would be better as a comment once you have the reputation. See the [how to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help understanding what makes a quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is influenced by what exactly is compared. When comparing two local files the view is influenced by the first & second selection. If using e.g. GIT the left hand side will always be what is present locally, the currently checked-out branch or local changes - so changing the branch will influence the view. When using SVN it is mostly the same, so left hand locally, right hand remotly.